# How do you deal with object type switching?

Tags: c#, object, types, switch-statement

In C# from time to time the issue creeps out. Usually I get an object value and then I have to call "real" function for it. Something like this:

```
if (type==typeof(byte))
  val = rs.GetByte(col);
else if (type==typeof(int))
  val = rs.GetInt32(col);
...
```

or

```
if (type==typeof(byte))
  Call((byte)val);
else if (type==typeof(int))
  Call((int)val);
...
```

I can see a textual pattern here, but I didn't come up with solution which would deal once for good with all the dirty work.

**How do you deal it?** You receive the object value and you have to either set it or pass it but not as an object but concrete type (PODs, Nullable of PODs and string) and...?

### Edits

Complete **example** (this one is the cause of the question):

```
    protected IRecord ReadRecord()
    {
        if (!ResultSet.Read())
            return null;

        IRecord record = CreateIRecord();

        var type = record.GetType();
        int column = -1;

        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            ++column;
            object val;

            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(byte))
                val = ResultSet.GetByte(column);
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(byte?))
                val = ResultSet.GetSqlByte(column).ToNullable();
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                val = ResultSet.GetInt32(column);
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
                val = ResultSet.GetSqlInt32(column).ToNullable();
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double))
                val = ResultSet.GetDouble(column);
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double?))
                val = ResultSet.GetSqlDouble(column).ToNullable();
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                val = ResultSet.GetDateTime(column);
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                val = ResultSet.GetSqlDateTime(column).ToNullable();
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                val = ResultSet.GetString(column);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property type {0}".Expand(prop.PropertyType.ToString()));

            prop.SetValue(record, val, null);
        }

        return record;


    }
```

Comment: You need to have more complete example code; as it is, what `type` and `rs` and `col` are is unclear, as is the relationship (or lack thereof) between them.

Comment: @Mr E that is not always possible, especially when dealing with simple types or different object hierarchies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a strategy pattern. Just put the strategies for each type in a hashtable and then you don't need the switches. However, you'll need one class per strategy. It is especially useful if you have complex logic.

If the logic is rather simple you could also use a Hashtable containing delegates.

```
//pseudo code
handlers.put(typeof(int), delegate(object value) { return something.GetInt32(value); });

//like this
var handler = handlers[type];
handler.Invoke(val);
```

Comment: You mean a dictionary <type,action>? I don't think it is more compact, unless you use some kind of call method name builder and use reflection to get the method and call it. Something like new MySwitcher(rs,"Get${TypeName}") for my first example.

Comment: yes, I mean a Dictionary, with type as key and possibly with an action as value. Of course you'll have to populate the dictionary in an initialization method. But it's easier to read and maintain than a lot of switches. Also, you don't really need reflection. You can wrap almost anything in a method or use anonymous delegates. That's pretty sweet syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Falcon, thank you -- the problem is, you have to populate this dictionary for each case. It is still kind of ugly (so I won't use it for my own, but thank you for sharing the idea).

Comment: There's no good solution for your problem. Of course you can go and use conventions for methods names and use reflection, like you stated before. That makes for nice, clean code, but can lead to pretty nasty runtime errors and could probably be slow performance-wise.  p.s. sometimes you just have to write a few lines of code *g*

Comment: @Falcon, runtime errors could be huge problems, agreed, but despite reflection speed, one could cache all methods in constructor call. So it would be resolved once (slow), and then used many times (fast).

Comment: And then again you'd have a cache, probably a lookup table which is probably a dictionary ;) Just try a few different things and take what you like best.

Answer (score 2):

You could clean it up a bit using the is operator:

```
if (MyType is BaseType)...
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but the main problem remains.

Comment: Where has that been hiding my entire life?